# How to point file path to installation directory?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

First project. I'm using an image file and in my code I am pointing to the location on my PC but when opened on someone else's PC, they would obviously not have the same directory, so how do I point to where the file will be on their PC?

I'm on windows, using Pycharm and Tkinter

```py
# Adds Background Image
filename = PhotoImage(file="D:\\Master\\Giveaway Gen\\Media\\numi.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import os
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #absolute direction
relative_path = "Media/numi.png"
absolute_file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, relative_path)
```

1. Get the absolute path
2. Join the relative path with absolute